# Eclipse and Maven: How to share code among modules?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have 1 maven project with 3 modules:

./project
./project-node
./project-master
./project-common

The first is just to allow me to execute mvn build to build all 3 modules at once.

I want to extract all common code between -node and -master to -common.

I don't know how to do it. -common has a bunch of Interfaces that are used by both -node and -master. Do I have to add project-common as a `<dependency>` to both? I wanted to avoid having to install project-common to the local repository every time I made a change... Looking for something lightweight as this initial stage of development.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use interfaces and classes of `project-common` within `project-node` and `project-master`, you have to add the `project-common` artifact as `<dependency>` in the pom of the projects you want to use the code in (in this case `project-node` and `project-master`).
You dont need to install dependency artifacts in your local repository if they are in your build reactor. So if you run `mvn compile` on `project`, all three artifacts are in the build reactor, so maven dont look for them in the local or remote repo. No need for installing here.

Comment: Can that workflow be used with the Eclipse Run command? Or does Run altogether skip Maven?

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly! m2eclipse added the dependency as a Project Reference! Just like I wanted!

Comment: Sorry but i don't use Eclipse so i cant give any support on that. If you are looking for an IDE with very nice maven support, check out `JetBrains IntelliJ` :x